# React Native - null is not an object (evaluating 'ValidStatusChanges.length')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am still new to React Native and am looking for some guidance

I am getting the error null is not an object (evaluating 'ValidStatusChanges.length') and cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the affected code

```
componentDidUpdate(currentProps) {
    const {
      incidentDetails: { ValidStatusChanges },
      assignedIncidents,
    } = currentProps.state.data;

    if (!ValidStatusChanges) {
      this.props.valueChange({
        storeName: "data",
        prop: "incidentDetails",
        nestedProp: ValidStatusChanges,
        value: []
        })
    }

    if (ValidStatusChanges.length === 0 && assignedIncidents.length !== 0) {
      this.props.valueChange({
        storeName: "data",
        prop: "assignedIncidents",
        value: [],
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: reason for this error is that `ValidStatusChanges` is undefined or null. As you can't use (.) Dot operator on null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Before making further checks make sure `ValidStatusChanges` is a valid object.

```js
if(ValidStatusChanges){
   if (ValidStatusChanges.length === 0 && assignedIncidents.length !== 0) {
      this.props.valueChange({
        storeName: "data",
        prop: "assignedIncidents",
        value: [],
      });
    }
}
```